# Large messages with Camel + ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to post a large message (JSON Format with +210k characters) on a Artemis Queue trough a endpoint Rest with Camel.

When I add a Camel Component with ActiveMQ Connection Factory  `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory - Version: 5.15.6)` I'm able to post the message with success.

But when I use the Artemis Connection Factory ( `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory - Version: 2.6.2)` the entire message isn't post in the Queue. The message was cut off reaming only 106725 characters.

Repository where I've create the examples: https://github.com/vitorvr/camel-amq

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [this Artemis documentation page](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/large-messages.html) for large message support in Artemis.

There is an attribute `minLargeMessageSize` that is by **default 100 kB** (roughly the remaining message size you mention). That setting means that **Artemis treats all messages that are more than 100 kB as large message and therefore handles them differently**.

Comment: Got it. Its works.
Just to test I used  `factory.setMinLargeMessageSize(1000000);`
Thanks so much.